# How to fill NaN in a column based on the values in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on this project where I need to fill a `NaN` cell from the `reason` column, but I need to cross-check with the `status` column first and fill in the appropriate values.

**The condition is:**

- If `STATUS` is "Invoiced" and `REASON` is `NaN`, then fill with "Not
  Applicable"
- If `STATUS` is "Lost Sale" and `REASON` is `NaN`, then fill with "Unknown"

---

I have tried this code:

```
data2 = np.where((data["SO_STATUS"] == "Invoiced")&(data["SO_LOSREASON"]=='NaN'),'null',"Not Applicable")
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['SO_STATUS'])
data= data.join(data2)
```

However, it says:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['SO_STATUS'], dtype='object')
```

I am not sure if what I did is correct or not since I still need the other data from `reason` column that are not `NaN`.
Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Try using direct column assignment:

```
data['SO_STATUS'] = np.where((data["SO_STATUS"] == "Invoiced") & data["SO_LOSREASON"].isna(),, "Not Applicable", "Unknown")
```

Comment: Hi, what if there is another condition where at least 6 variables from the status column and NaN from the reason column need to be filled with a new variable which is "Potential Sale"?

Comment: @nizana Use `np.select`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `where`, thus it is easy to add any other condition:

```
data['new_column'] = (data['SO_STATUS'].map({'Invoiced': 'Not Applicable',
                                             'Lost Sale': 'Unknown',
                                             # add other here: 'Other': 'other',
                                            })
                                       .where(data['SO_LOSREASON'].isna())
                      )
```

example (setting a new column `new_column` for clarity):

```
   SO_STATUS SO_LOSREASON      new_column
0   Invoiced          NaN  Not Applicable
1  Lost Sale          NaN         Unknown
2      Other          NaN             NaN
3   Invoiced          abc             NaN
```

Comment: Hi, how do I merge the new column to the previous reason column? since I still need the other data that are not NaN from the previous reason column?

Comment: Use `where`: `A.where(condition, B)` gives `A` if `condition` is True else `B`

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand, do I still put it inside the previous condition after .where(data['SO_LOSREASON'].isna())?